# Mantle drills for harvesting geothermal energy

Tags: science-based, engineering, materials

In the mid-2020s, scientists try to harvest geothermal energy, by using drill equipment that drill deep into the Earth's crust and into the mantle, so that the intense heat can be harvested by pumping water into the hole and using the steam to spin a turbine.

The drill itself is made of a durable titanium-tungsten alloy, which is durable and can withstand high temperatures and intense pressures. A black diamond is installed at the tip of the drill, to cut through the rocks. The hole formed is about 6ft wide.

Is this design feasible for harvesting geothermal energy?

Comment: "This tag may not be used alone. This tag may not be used with the science-fiction, hard-science, or internal-consistency tags."

Comment: Not an answer, but no.  We have titanium/tungsten alloys.  We have diamond tipped drills.  Neither of those allow us to drill into the mantle, because rock stops behaving like rock before you hit the mantle.  The problem is not the drill, it is the borehole.

Comment: Is there a worldbuilding problem here (see [help/on-topic])? This sounds like an engineering question. The answer is, "given the proper materials, technology, and time, of course it is."

Comment: Your description... That is not how diamond drills used to make boreholes work... A diamond drill has many cheap diamonds embedded into a steel drill bit. Why the ridiculously huge diameter($$$-super expensive)? Your question suggests to me you have not done research into how diamond drills operate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't go all the [way to the mantle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/716408/is-it-possible-to-heat-an-artificial-lake-using-the-temperatures-from-deep-bore/716439#716439).... Find a magma pool closer to the surface. This has been experimented with in Hawaii and Iceland.
The figure below shows a concept. This avoids the 25 degree C per kilometer drilling. The problems with extracting energy from boreholes are related to how to transport the energy with a fluid, how does the rock cool down, and how the heat transfer keeps the rock around the borehole hot.

[image: Coaxial Borehole]

But for your question, innovations in drilling would be useful. Also you would think about how wide to make the borehole so you can have good movement of fluids.

Edit: Also you don't need to get fantastically hot to be useful. A lot depends on your working fluid. Water is probably the easiest and cheapest, but at the surface it boils at only 100 C.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with drilling deep in the crust is not the durability/hardness of the tip, but that at those depth the rocks start behaving like a very viscous goo rather than something hard that can be crushed. Diamond might be good at crushing, not at dealing with viscous materials.

Therefore the drilled rocks tend to clump around the tip, clogging the hole that has been drilled.

And we are talking about the problems they experience when drilling the Kola hole, which just dented the crust with 12 km. The mantle is way deeper than that.

Those considerations apart, as of today there no economic justification to go that deep to gather energy when there are more economic alternatives.

Comment: I didn't know that; but it seems like long before you have problems with rocks so hot they are viscous; you have plenty of heat for basically turning water into steam to power a turbine. (Maybe you could even put the turbine down the hole, so the steam doesn't have to travel all the way back up the hole; just the electrical current comes out of the hole.)

Comment: @Amadeus then you would have to pump up the water to cool it down. Plus magnets and high temperature do not go well together

Answer (score 2):

Frame challenge. **Don't drill it, melt it! **. There is actually a company in the US trialing new technology to reach depths deep enough to harness geothermal energy at virtually any point on the surface of the earth not just shallow hot spots like now using a device called a **gyrotron** to melt the through dense rock strata normally found deeper in the crust. The gyrotron melts the rock in it path which then cools & solidifies behind the drill sealing the walls of the shaft as it goes.

The drill rate is apparently about 5 meters an hour which is slow by conventional standards at shallower depths but much faster than normal drills can manage at the depths you need to reach for reliable geothermal power (anywhere but at shallow hot spots). Apparently the idea is to speed up the completion of each shaft by starting with a conventional drill then switching over to the gyrotron when the drill reaches dense rock. Power consumption is also apparently quite modest.

[Quaise Energy](https://www.quaise.energy/)

**EDIT:** You don't need one large (6 foot!!!) bore hold. That would be counterproductive from an engineering perspective (massive challenges around stabilizing a shaft that wide and no redundancy etc.) Instead geothermal power plants are built around a network of multiple, standard sized bore holes).

Comment: a very interesting and enthusiastic link!